# Use three chapter title definitions

Tags: memoir, chapters

my chapter titles are rather long, which is not a problem on text pages, but for the ToC. Hence, I use this command to provide two versions:

```
\chapter[Category\\ This is my long title]{Category -- This is my long title}
```

This works well, of course :-) Now my problem is that I'm using the `memoir` package, which places the chapter title on every odd page. For this, it uses the the chapter title provided for the ToC, but I want to use the other one to avoid line breaks in my header bar. Maybe I could provide three chapter titles, one for the text page, one for the ToC, and one for the header bar?!

Following my MWE. The resulting PDF illustrates on pages 3 and 4 a line break in the head row of the page I would like to avoid. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{~|~}

\chapterstyle{madsen}
\pagestyle{companion}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter[Category\\ This is my very long title]{Category -- This is my very long title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Test ABC}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Test ABC}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Test ABC}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's neither `madsen` or the `companion` style that produces this. The column titles in the headers use the short ToC `[Chapter\\...]` as default value, that's the cause.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I updated my question, thank you!

Comment: as far as I know memoir provide tvo optional chapter fields, one for toc, one for heading, see memoir manual, pp. 75: \chapter[<toc-title>][>head-title>]{<title>}; \chapter*[<head-title>]{<title>}.

Comment: @Zarko awesome, thank you! Please move your comment to an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let be my comment transformed to the answer. The memoir is very advanced document class, which among many improvements of book class also provide addition ability to define appearance of chapter, section etc title in TOC, heading and in the text. So, for chapter one can say:

```
  \chapter[<toc-title>][>head-title>]{<title>}; 
  \chapter*[<head-title>]{<title>}
```

For more information see Memoir manual, page 75.